# Размещение pdf файла на сайт через форму php

Tags: php

Как реализовать отправку и размещение pdf файла на сайт через форму php ? Научился отправлять через метод Post файл на сервер, но не доходит, как разместить конкретно этот отправленный файл на сайте

Comment: что именно не ясно то? вот загрузили вы файл. знаете путь к нему. что мешает ссылку на него сделать теперь?

Comment: я понимаю, что при использовании move_uploaded_file я отправляю файл условно в папку image сайта и руками смогу прописать путь в коде html потом, но я не понимаю, как это автоматизировать и размещать условную картинку на сайт прямо после отправки её по форме через POST

Comment: чтобы это автоматизировать, вам надо сохранить пути к своим файлам куда-то, в базу данных, файл или еще что-то. Потом читать это хранилище и на основании этого списка выводить ссылки на страницу.
Либо вы можете прочитать директорию и вывести все файлы, которые там находятся.